# Dropdownlist with sqldatareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

my dropdownlist HTML5

```
<select runat="server" id="ddlStateLegalRes" name="ddlStateLegalRes"></select>
```

On my page load I am binding my dropdownlist to a list collection with a list of states

```
Original question was answered created a new question as it is a different erorr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need to do this:

```
ddlStateLegalRes.Items.FindByValue(sdr["STATEOFLEGALRESIDENCE"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Comment: hutchonoid thanks for your response can you please see my updated question and let me know if you could help?

Comment: I would move this                     List<StateList> states = ops.getStates(); to outside of the is not post back. I suspect that on post back u are not populating again.

Comment: The original question was answered, you should leave it as accepted. Create a new question & send me it pls.

Comment: Sorry hutchonoid last time I did that I got yelled at for not unaccepting the answer and editing the question that is the only reason I did that. But I will do it again and hope not to get yelled at again so many rules here hard to keep up :)

Comment: Also i thought the same thing and tried that but it still results in the same error

Comment: There is the link and also reaccepted this answer thanks for all your help

Comment: Will take a look now.